# how to override package.json name and version fields

Tags: npm

If the `package.json` is as follows :

```json
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "0.0.1"
  "scripts": {
    "test": "program.js" 
  }
}
```

`program.js` uses npm version during execution.

Is there a way to override the `package.json` version so that `program.js` takes the overridden version?

Comment: What do you mean? What doesn't work?

Comment: I mean is there a way to override package.json version using environment variable or any other. Just like we can override package.json config.